Multi-tenant in micro-service architecture in NestJS using typeORM and Posgres
I want to design a multi-tenant microservice architecture in nest JS using typeORM and Postgres. I have found this article which is quite helpful https://thomasvds.com/schema-based-multitenancy-with-nest-js-type-orm-and-postgres-sql/ but this is only for a single service in nestJS. I can make follow this pattern and add this in every single microservice but I don't want to code redundancy is there any way to implement it?
https://thomasvds.com/schema-based-multitenancy-with-nest-js-type-orm-and-postgres-sql/
I followed this article but this is only for single service/app in nestJS.
